# Portrait and landscape orientation layout in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I want to print portrait and landscape maps on a single page. Is there any expression to do that?

Comment: Setting up and using the Atlas Tool can take some time but the automation (export) is well worth it. https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/automating_map_creation.html

Comment: I dont understand what you're asking

Comment: It's not really clear what you are aiming for. The *page* is portrait or landscape, you can make the map frames any aspect ratio/orientation you want. Please include some extra details clarifying your problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you make an Atlas, you can define different pages and use the datadefinded override of the "Exclude page from Exports" checkbox (under the page properties). there you use a boolean criteria to define which page will be exported in portrait or landscape. In the example below I used the field "fid": if fid will be even it will be exported in landscape, if it will be odd in landscape.

[image]